# Codename one rename file when size exceeds limit

Tags: codenameone

In my app project I'd like to keep a log of standard output for debug purpose, and I would like to get e.g. only 500kb of most recent part of log file. What I am currently thinking is to rename the log file to another name when it exceeded 500kb ("oldlog"), and the old "oldlog" be overwritten.

However, I could not decide which api to use. The Storage class provide entriSize() method to conveniently check the size of current log, but cannot rename a file easily. The FileSystemStorage class does have a rename method, but only provided api to check size of directory.

I am currently doing the following, which doesn't seems convenient:

```
if (Storage.getInstance().entrySize("log") >= size) {
InputStream is = Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("log");
OutputStream os = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream("oldlog");
Util.copy(is, os);
}
```

Is there a better way then opening two streams? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [FileSystemStorage.getLength()](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/FileSystemStorage.html#getLength-java.lang.String-) method to find the size of a file.